# Use ascii.write() with different column lengths

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, numpy, astropy

I want to save several values (floats & ints) and arrays into a text file. I tried using an astropy table and `ascii.write()` but got a value error.

> ValueError: Elements in list initialization must be either Column or list-like

Code:

```
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.io import ascii

table = Table([x, y, propNum, inc], names=('x', 'y', 'propNum', 'inc'))

ascii.write(table, 'test4.dat')
```

Inputs:

```
x = [6512905, 6291646, 3667192, -358003, -4246455, -6512905, -6291646,  -3667192, 358003, 4246455]
y = [-1739743, 2420707, 5656530, 6731751, 5235671, 1739743, -2420707, -5656530, -6731751, -5235671]
propNum = 100
inc = 51.762
```

Desired Output:

```
6512905, -1739743, 100, 51.762
6291646, 2420707
3667192, 5656530
...      ...
```

Comment: Can't you just repeat the `propNum` and `inc` values N times?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest explicitly creating a masked table, which offers more flexibility in the length and position of the shorter columns:

```
x = [6512905, 6291646, 3667192, -358003, -4246455, -6512905, -6291646,  -3667192, 358003, 4246455]
y = [-1739743, 2420707, 5656530, 6731751, 5235671, 1739743, -2420707, -5656530, -6731751, -5235671]
propNum = np.concatenate([[100], np.zeros(len(x)-1, dtype='i')])
inc = np.concatenate([[51.762], np.zeros(len(x)-1)])

mtab = Table([x, y, propNum, inc], names=('x', 'y', 'propNum', 'inc'), masked=True)
mtab['propNum'][1:].mask = True
mtab['inc'][1:].mask = True
mtab.write('/dev/stdout', format='ascii', overwrite=True)

x y propNum inc
6512905 -1739743 100 51.762
6291646 2420707 "" ""
3667192 5656530 "" ""
-358003 6731751 "" ""
-4246455 5235671 "" ""
-6512905 1739743 "" ""
-6291646 -2420707 "" ""
-3667192 -5656530 "" ""
358003 -6731751 "" ""
4246455 -5235671 "" ""
```

I think there might also be options to customise the output of the masked values, but I could not dig that up in the docs right now.

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` arrays for `propNum` and `inc` when simple lists are enough?

Comment: In general for scientific code it's better to use Numpy arrays, especially if they are going to be used as a mask (in fact Table is going to convert them to arrays anyways if they aren't already).

Comment: And I think `np.zeros` or `np.ones` makes for a cleaner interface than multiples of list – besides being vastly faster for datasets of any significant length. Though in that case cutting the `np.concatenate` will be much more efficient still:
`%timeit inc = [51.762] + 99999999*[0]
1.17 s ± 41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit inc = np.concatenate([[51.762], np.zeros(99999999)])
816 ms ± 4.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit inc = np.zeros(10**9); inc[0] = 51.762
41.1 µs ± 592 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loop`

Comment: Good point--better (in this case anyways) to just initialize an array of zeros and then fill in the few non-zero entries.

Comment: Is there a way to justify the columns in a masked table?

Comment: Figured it out `ascii.write(mtab, 'testY.dat', format='ecsv')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the `astropy.table` package supports generating a table with different length columns.

A simple way to get around this is to just repeat the values in the columns that have only one element.

```
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.io import ascii


x = [6512905, 6291646, 3667192, -358003, -4246455, -6512905, -6291646,  -3667192, 358003, 4246455]
y = [-1739743, 2420707, 5656530, 6731751, 5235671, 1739743, -2420707, -5656530, -6731751, -5235671]
propNum = 100
inc = 51.762

table = Table([x, y, [propNum] * len(x), [inc] * len(x)], names=('x', 'y', 'propNum', 'inc'))

ascii.write(table, 'test4.dat')
```

which results in:

```
x y propNum inc
6512905 -1739743 100 51.762
6291646 2420707 100 51.762
3667192 5656530 100 51.762
-358003 6731751 100 51.762
-4246455 5235671 100 51.762
-6512905 1739743 100 51.762
-6291646 -2420707 100 51.762
-3667192 -5656530 100 51.762
358003 -6731751 100 51.762
4246455 -5235671 100 51.762
```

Similarly, you can extend the last two columns to contain any string you want to signal an empty row:

```
fillVal = 'NA'
propNum = [100] + [fillVal] * (len(x) - 1)
inc = [51.762] + [fillVal] * (len(x) - 1)

table = Table([x, y, propNum, inc], names=('x', 'y', 'propNum', 'inc'))
ascii.write(table, 'test4.dat')
```

which gives:

```
x y propNum inc
6512905 -1739743 100 51.762
6291646 2420707 NA NA
3667192 5656530 NA NA
-358003 6731751 NA NA
-4246455 5235671 NA NA
-6512905 1739743 NA NA
-6291646 -2420707 NA NA
-3667192 -5656530 NA NA
358003 -6731751 NA NA
4246455 -5235671 NA NA
```

Notice that this only works if the missing values are *not* in the first row. If they are, you could still use this approach with some modifications-

Comment: I tried out the 'NA' solution and got an error message `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')`

Comment: I tried the other solution and got `ValueError: masked should be one of True, False, None`

Comment: Try copying the code from the answer and run that code. I suspect you modified your original code in some way.

Comment: Better to use a mask and explicit fill values: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/masking.html